# How can I adjust in my Jquery Code see description of problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently right now it adds up a visit counter. Example: I have a text field and I type 1 then next text field I type of 20 so 1 of 20 visits. Next document I use it uses the same counter so it would automatically calculate up the visits for me to say 2 of 20 visits. What I want to figure out is if I need to change the counter to say 3 of 20 instead of 2 out of 20 how can I adjust the code to save my changes.

Currently the counter reverts back after I save my document with the counter in it- reverts back to 2 of 20 not reflecting me changing it to 3 of 20.

```
window.onload = function(e){ 
    setCurrentCount('previousvisit','currentvisit','totalvisits');
}

function setCurrentCount(prevId, currentId, totalId ) {

    var prevEle = document.getElementById(prevId);
    var currentEle = document.getElementById(currentId);
    var totalEle = document.getElementById(totalId );

    if( prevEle && currentEle && totalEle ) {

        var totalVal = parseInt(totalEle.value);

        if( totalVal > 0) {

            var prevVal = 0;

            // check the prev value
            // if it is empty, set it to the total value

            if(! prevEle.value ) {
                //currentEle.value = totalVal;
                prevEle.value = totalVal;
            } else {
                currentEle.value = parseInt(prevEle.value) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the counter to reflect a different number outside the initial calculation I want it to save it- right now it reverts back to the number it actually should be in the calculation.

Comment: It is totally unclear to me what you are asking and in what context the included code snippet should work. Can you try to clean up your question so anyone who is not you might also understand it?

Comment: is there a way to post screenshots. I work in the medical industry building HTML templates and I am using jquery on one- If I could show you a screenshot it would make more sense.

Comment: @JochemKuijpers can I email you and send the screenshots of what I'm looking at. Its the only way you will get what I'm talking about...

Comment: You can add screenshots by editing your post and clicking the "photo" icon above the text box.

Comment: Though note that screenshots usually don't work well. If you can, please create a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem you are having: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "Currently the counter reverts back after I save my document with the counter in it- reverts back to 2 of 20 not reflecting me changing it to 3 of 20." Does this mean you submit a form?

Comment: @JayJordan yes technically

Comment: When you submit a form, unless you `preventDefault()`; it's going to cause a POST. Unless you have a way of updating your counter after a POST, then it will reset every time.